# My Sony Vaio laptop crashed during restoring it to its factory settings

Tags: windows-vista, sony-vaio

Early this summer my computer caught a virus. My virus protection ran out a few weeks before so I was trying to get rid of it but it kept giving me pop up windows everywhere. I caved in and decided to restore it back to its factory settings. But something went wonky because it stopped half way and now its stuck in this limbo. What it says:

> Windows Failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be
>   the cause. To fix the problem:
>
> 1. Insert your windows installation disc and restart your computer.
> 2. Choose your language settings, and the click "Next."
> 3. Click "Repair your computer."
>
> If you do not have this disc, contact your system administrator or
>   computer manufacturer for assistance.
>
> File: /Boot/BCD
>
> Status: `0xc000000f`
>
> Info: An error occurred while attempting to read the boot
>   configuration data.

I need a Windows Vista start up disk, a Sony start up disk, or something else that can help me fix this problem. Nothing else I've tried has worked.

The place where I bought it from told me to get the disk since repairing it would cost way too much money. If somebody could tell me where I can download that software for free or buy it cheap, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Start the restore process over from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Contact Sony support.  They should provide you a replacement CD for free.